# How can I use RMMapView in Interface Builder?

Tags: ios, openstreetmap, mapbox

I am using the Mapbox iOS SDK to show offline OpenStreetMaps data in my iOS app. I have successfully done this programatically, but now I would like to do this using the Interface Builder. To do so I have created a subclass of UIViewController with a .xib file and put a UIView into the main view of the xib. Then in the identity inspector I changed this view's Custom Class to RMMapView and put an IBOutlet into the header of of the UIViewController and connected it with the Custom RMMapView object in the xib.

```
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet RMMapView *mapView;
```

So far I think this should be correct. When I start the app the RMMapView is created in the nib and shows the default behavior, i.e. it shows a map with the "Example" watermarks. Therefore I need to set the appropriate tilesource, so far I did this in the viewDidLoad method of the ViewController, something like

```
 RMMBTilesSource *tileSource = [[RMMBTilesSource alloc] initWithTileSetResource:@"mymap" ofType:@"mbtiles"];
```

followed by

```
[self.mapView setTileSource:tileSource]
```

or alternatively

```
[self.mapView addTileSource:tileSource]
```

However, even after these calls the mapView's RMTileSourcesContainer has still value nil and from what I can tell the set/addTileSource calls practically don't have an effect. 
In my opinion the problem is that in RMMapView initWithCoder has not been overwritten and therefore the RMMapView is not initialized properly through the nib, most importantly the RMTileSourcesContainer is not initialized. Is this really the case ? Why has initWitCoder not been overwritten ? How should I go about using RMMapView in the Interface Builder ?
Thanks for your help!!

Comment: Is it tileSource == nil after allocation?

Comment: no the RMMapview does not have a variable tileSource, all tileSources are in RMTileSourcesContainer, which is nil

Comment: Why do you use RMTileSourcesContainer? If you have tileSource just add to _mapView and it will work fine.

Comment: ok ? which method should I use to add the tileSource ? the addTileSource and the setTileSource methods give the behavior I described and there is no tileSource variable I could use directly.

Comment: And I don't understand, why you cannot show your map through UIView. You will save more time.

Comment: what do you mean "show your map through UIView" ? I am using a UIView from the object library in Interface Builder and change its class to RMMapView.

Comment: [self.view addSubview:_mapView];
Add your RMMapView on UIView as subView. Don't the change class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to try this in `-viewWillAppear:` or later, not `-viewDidLoad`. Due to the way the `RMMapView` is based on `UIScrollView`, the map view needs to added to a live view hierarchy before it can set its parameters.

Comment: Even in `-viewWillAppear:` you can't configure MapView properly, best way is to do it in `-viewDidAppear:`... it's bad code design of RoteMe SDK cos it should be possible to configure any UIView descendants after loading from nib file. Time for Refactoring !!!))